# Fetch a To-Many Entity

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have two entities pictured below. How do I fetch all of the `Node`s for a certain `Trip`? And how do I specify the `Trip` that I want to fetch?

[image]

Comment: Do you otherwise already have Core Data setup and a managed object context?

Comment: Yes. I also have a Table View showing the list of trips trips that is sorted by `timeStarted`, but I want to be able to tap that cell with a trip date and go to my other view that contains a text view so I can see all of the nodes saved in that trip.

Comment: See expanded answer below on how it's super easy with a table view to obtain your Trip using objectAtIndexPath:

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I've got some learning to do on `NSFetchedResultsController`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a managed object context, you'll fetch a group of of Trips using a fetched results controller. You can place a predicate on a fetch, and you'll get back only the record(s) that you've matched. You'll need to review the documentation on NSFetchedResultsController to learn how to obtain the Trip you want from CoreData.

Once you have a Trip, it's easy to get your nodes. Call:

```
[trip nodesInTrip]
```

You'll get a set back.

If you're using a table view, it's even easier (this assumes your fetchedResultsController is your table views data source):

```
-(void)didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath {

    Trip *selectedTrip = [[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSArray *arrayOfNodes = [selectedTrip nodesInTrip];
```